# javascript array to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

i want to send a javascript array to php using jquery ajax.

```
$.post("controllers/ajaxcalls/users.php",
{
    links: links
});
```

where the second 'links' is a javascript array.

when i've got this array:

```
'1' ...
    '1' => "comment1"
    '2' => "link1"
    '3' => "link2"
    '4' => "link3"
'2' ...
    '1' => "comment2"
    '2' => "link4"
```

then using:

```
var jsonLinks = JSON.stringify(links);
alert(jsonLinks);
```

will give me:

```
[null,[null,"comment1","link1","link2","link3"],[null,"comment2","link4"]]
```

seems to me that something is wrong. what are the null:s and i cant use json_decode on php side to get the elements.

what function should i use to convert it to json and how do i access it on the php side?

tried this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/ but it will give exactly the same output as JSON.stringify() (they also say that in the documentation).

have struggled with this in some hours now...would appreciate some SPECIFIC help.

i just want to send an array from javascript to php...why is that so damn difficult:/

Comment: Why did you ask this question again? You already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138812/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the **null** part, JavaScript arrays are numeric and zero based:

```
>>> var foo = [];
>>> foo[5] = 'Five';
"Five"
>>> foo
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "Five"]
```

On the contrary, PHP allows missing (and mixed) keys:

```
<?php

$foo = array();
$foo[5] = 'Five';
print_r($foo);

?>

Array
(
    [5] => Five
)
```

If you want to use arrays, I suggest you make them zero-based and prevent missing values. Otherwise, you could probably use objects instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are some jQuery plugin that can encode to JSON *(and decode from JSON)*.

For instance, you can take a look at [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) *(quoting)* :

> This plugin exposes four new functions
>   onto the $, or jQuery object:
>
> - `toJSON`: Serializes a javascript object, number, string, or arry into
>     JSON.
> - `evalJSON`: Converts from JSON to Javascript, quickly, and is trivial.
> - `secureEvalJSON`: Converts from JSON to Javascript, but does so while
>     checking to see if the source is
>     actually JSON, and not with other
>     Javascript statements thrown in.
> - `quoteString`: Places quotes around a string, and inteligently escapes any
>     quote, backslash, or control
>     characters.

Comment: that give me the same output as using JSON.stringify(). if its nothing wrong with the output how do i access the elements? i tried with alert(jsonLinks[1][1]) but it gave an undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are trying to read this in your PHP script, but if it is related to you having 1-based arrays rather than 0-based arrays, then in javascript, you can remove the nulls (zeroth element) with:

```
var jsonLinks = JSON.stringify(links.slice(1));
```

Comment: i dont get the null:s...what are those? i have never access arrays sent through javascript but i guess its $links = json_decode($_POST['links']), then just use $links[1][1] etc. but it doesnt work. so i guess something is wrong cause why do i get all the NULLS?

Comment: You get the nulls because you are starting your array at index "1". Javascript arrays are zero-based, so index 0 (links[0], links[1][0] and links[2][0]) will be "null" (not set)